# how to check if file exists outside of current working directory in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find if a file exists that is not in the current directory. The file is here:

`~/Documents/project/data.csv`

I am trying to locate it by absolute path like this:

```
os.path.isfile(f'~/Documents/project/data.csv')
```

I always get false because I am running this code from outside of `~/Documents/project/`. I understand os.path.isfile only works from the current directory. How do I modify my code above to return a bool if the file exists?

Comment: When working with filenames, Python does not automatically know that `~` means "my home directory".  You have to use the `os.path.expanduser()` function.  Otherwise, it looks for a directory literally named `~`.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you using?  As of 3.4 you can use the `pathlib` library functions:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path("~/Documents/project/data.csv")
p.exists()
```

Comment: You'll have to get the absolute location of `~` first, so it should probably be closer to:
`p = Path.home() / Path("Documents/project/data.csv")`